# How to optimize a dateframe processing in pandas?

Tags: pandas, performance, optimization, jupyter-notebook

I have a following DF.

```
    Date        Time        Open    High    Low     Close
0   2010-01-03  17:00:00    1.4301  1.4304  1.4301  1.4304
1   2010-01-03  17:01:00    1.4303  1.4303  1.4303  1.4303
```

I need to normalize prices inside of each day, so its necessery to divide each day price by its first value of the day, so each day would start with 1.0.
Ive written the following code, but it works extrimely slow, how do I improve it? I find it too complicated, is there an elegant way?

```
for year in range(2010, 2021):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        for day in range(1, 31):
            mutdf = dfc.loc[(dfc['Date'].dt.year == year) & (dfc['Date'].dt.month == month) & (dfc['Date'].dt.day == day), 
                            ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
            if mutdf.empty:
                continue
            mutdf['Open'] = mutdf['Open'].divide(mutdf.iloc[0, 0])
            mutdf['High'] = mutdf['High'].divide(mutdf.iloc[0, 1])
            mutdf['Low'] = mutdf['Low'].divide(mutdf.iloc[0, 2])
            mutdf['Close'] = mutdf['Close'].divide(mutdf.iloc[0, 3])
            dfc.loc[(dfc['Date'].dt.year == year) & (dfc['Date'].dt.month == month) & (dfc['Date'].dt.day == day), 
                    ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']] = mutdf
```

Desired output:

```
    Date        Time        Open    High    Low     Close
0   2010-01-03  17:00:00    1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.000000
1   2010-01-03  17:01:00    1.00014 0.99993 1.00014 0.999930
2   2010-01-03  17:02:00    1.00007 0.99993 1.00000 0.999930
3   2010-01-03  17:03:00    1.00007 0.99986 1.00007 0.999860
4   2010-01-03  17:04:00    1.00000 0.99986 0.99979 0.999720
5   2010-01-03  17:06:00    1.00000 0.99979 0.99993 0.999790
6   2010-01-03  17:08:00    0.99993 0.99986 0.99993 0.999790
7   2010-01-03  17:09:00    0.99993 0.99979 0.99979 0.999581
8   2010-01-03  17:10:00    0.99986 0.99979 0.99986 0.999790
9   2010-01-03  17:12:00    1.00007 0.99993 1.00007 0.999930
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` on `Date` and divide by first value:

```
df["Open"] = df.groupby("Date")["Open"].transform(lambda d: d/d.iat[0])

print (df)

         Date      Time     Open    High     Low   Close
0  2010-01-03  17:00:00  1.00000  1.4304  1.4301  1.4304
1  2010-01-03  17:01:00  1.00014  1.4303  1.4303  1.4303
```

Working on all columns in one go:

```
col = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

print (df.set_index(["Date","Time"])
         .groupby("Date").apply(lambda d: d[col]/df[col].iloc[0])
         .reset_index())

         Date      Time     Open     High      Low    Close
0  2010-01-03  17:00:00  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000
1  2010-01-03  17:01:00  1.00014  0.99993  1.00014  0.99993
```

Answer (score 1):

- Financial data usually comes in a standard form with a single `datetime` column, not a `date` and `time` column.

  - My assumption is, a `datetime` was separated to facilitate the current process presented by the OP.

    - If this is the case, do not split the column.
    - Make certain the `datetime` column is a `datetime` `dtype` with `df.info()`
- If the data does come with separate columns, it's better to join them into a `datetime` `dtype`.
- With a `datetime` `dtype` there are many [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) methods for extracting a specific component (e.g. `.dt.date`)
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) to access the first row off all the columns.
- This is similar to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212814) from [Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik) except the `Datetime` column makes the `groupby` calculation more straight forward.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2010-01-03', '2010-01-03'], 'Time': ['17:00:00', '17:01:00'], 'Open': [1.4301, 1.4303], 'High': [1.4304, 1.4303], 'Low': [1.4301, 1.4303], 'Close': [1.4304, 1.4303]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert Date to a datetime
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# convert Time to a timedelta
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

# create a single Datetime column
df['Datetime'] = df.Date + df.Time

# drop Date and Time
df = df.drop(columns=['Date', 'Time'])

# set Datetime as the index
df = df.set_index('Datetime')

# display(df)

                       Open    High     Low   Close
Datetime                                           
2010-01-03 17:00:00  1.4301  1.4304  1.4301  1.4304
2010-01-03 17:01:00  1.4303  1.4303  1.4303  1.4303

# groupby the date and normalize all rows
dfg = df.groupby(df.index.date).transform(lambda row: row/row.iat[0])

# display(dfg)

                        Open     High      Low    Close
Datetime                                               
2010-01-03 17:00:00  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000
2010-01-03 17:01:00  1.00014  0.99993  1.00014  0.99993
```

Comment: Thank you, Im not cool with pandas yet, so it was easier for me to keep date and time in 2 columns, your solutions also works well!